# improper display of an app on nexus 5 marshmallow devices

Tags: android

i got a very weird type of problem while developing a basic android app.
While I've created an app in which the background image of an app is visible to all the devices except nexus devices of android marshmallow. Kindly help me in solving the error. 
Below is the code and screenshot attached.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGs1z.png]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/abst"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="project.scytech.mi_agenda.LoginActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        layout="@layout/appname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/loginLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="16dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextDomainName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/domainName"
            android:inputType="textUri"
            android:textColorHint="#FFF8E5" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextUsername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:textColorHint="#FFF8E5" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@string/username"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColorHint="#FFF8E5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="loginClicked"
            android:text="@string/login" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are enforcing an image to a relative layout background. The system might not work properly. Why don't you try ImageView and decode Bitmap.

Comment: how to decode bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use an `ImageView` and set it as background.

It means:

> Use a RelativeLayout or a FrameLayout and define your ImageView as the
>   first child. The first objects defined are the lowest in the z-order
>   (i.e. they will be "below" the other views).
>
> From: [Setting an ImageView to the background Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207230/setting-an-imageview-to-the-background-android)

To fit it to whole screen device use `match_parent` or `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Your code should look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

//Rest of widgets......
```

Check also: [How to make image fill RelativeLayout background without stretching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275897/how-to-make-image-fill-relativelayout-background-without-stretching)

It should work